# Selecting n rows from several csv files and writing to new files in same directory using R

Tags: r, loops, csv, subset

This is likely a very straightforward question, but I have yet to find an answer/solution.

I have a folder with several csv files. My goal is to iterate through all of the files, select n rows from each, and write the selected rows to separate files. My searches have only returned how to do this for individual files.

```
temp = list.files(pattern = '*.csv')

for (i in 1:length(temp)) {
   i = as.data.frame(i) 
   n120 = i[120, ]
   outFile = paste(file_path_sans_ext(i), "_120.csv", sep="")
   write.csv(n120, file = outFile)
}
```

Temp returns all of the files of interest. The for loop, however, does not return the first 120 rows with all columns of the called csv file, but rather NA. Is this because R is storing the list of files as a character string?

What is the recommended way to access and iterate through each csv file in the list?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `apply` but several other iterators could work with a different approach, including a `for` loop or `lapply`. This code example uses a temporary directory to prevent anybody running this code from messing up their working directories. Remove the `setwd()` commands when running this locally.

```
library(tidyverse) # dplyr and friends
library(stringr)   # For parsing file names

old_wd <- getwd()
setwd(tempdir())   # Use a temporary directory
```

Create a few dummy .csv files in the temporary directory. Again, you'll probably want to remove this when you're using this code on your local machine.

```
demo <- tibble(a = rnorm(327), b = rnorm(327))
write_csv(demo, "demo1.csv")
write_csv(demo, "demo2.csv")
write_csv(demo, "demo3.csv")
```

Create a list of all .csv files in the working directory.

```
file_list <- list.files() %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  filter(str_detect(value, ".csv"))
```

The function `parse_csv` extracts the first 120 lines of a file and then saves that data as a new .csv file. It returns TRUE when it runs correctly. Feel free to make the file names prettier.

```
parse_csv <- function(file) {
  print(file)
  read_csv(file) %>%
    head(120) %>%
    write_csv(paste0(file, "-head.csv"))

  return(TRUE)
}
```

Now `apply` the function across each row of the data (`MARGIN = 1`).

```
apply(file_list, MARGIN = 1, parse_csv)
```

Restore the previous working directory.

```
setwd(old_wd)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested using the dummy variables but received errors for the tibble: "Error in tibble(a = rnorm(327), b = rnorm(327)): no column names detected in 'frame_data()' call". Added column names, but it returned that the columns are not the same length. Created a random df, and got "Error: data is not a data frame when listing csv files in the temp directory. Using my actual data, I used parse_csv function on 'files = list.files(path=old_wd, pattern="*.csv")'  and then 'apply' using MARGIN = 1. Still receive an error (dim(x) must have positive length). May I ask what I should change?